# Unable to add margin-right in a row of posts

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Right now I have 3 posts in a row, 3 posts in the next row, and 1 post in the next row, and so on.  I am trying to add space in-between the posts that have 3 in a row.  Every time I add css margin-right:25px; to .col-mod-4 { it adds the space but 1 post gets knocked off the row, and instead I have 3 rows of 2 posts.  Does anyone have any solutions?  (I have attached a dropbox link with screenshots of the problem)

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fbi17l2ortzpqkk/AACDm2XIcvJDjouAb0zPilfVa?dl=0

Here is my index.php

```html
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: learningwordpress
 */
 
get_header();
 
$i = 0;
 
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 14,
    'paged' => 1
);
 
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
 
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
 
        if( $i %2 == 1 ) {
                   $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>      
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>

 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>      
            <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
 <?php $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-4">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
            <?php

        }
        else {
         $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="post col-md-12">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('large-thumbnail'); ?>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p>
                    <?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?>
                    <a class="moretext" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read more</a>
                </p>
            </article>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
}
else {
    echo '<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>';
}
get_footer();
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `padding-right` instead of `margin-right`?

Comment: Yes, I've already tried padding-right and it did nothing.

Comment: Maybe you'll be better putting your content between a container inside each col-md-4. With this container, you can set a padding or a margin inside the col-md-4

Answer (score 0):

Try padding-right instead of margin-right